# Custom annotation like @Value

Tags: spring

I need to create a means to add a custom annotation like

```
@Value("${my.property}")
```

However, in my case I need to get the value from a database rather then a properties file.

Basically I would like to create a bean on container startup that reads in property name value pairs from a database and can then inject these into fields belonging to other beans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Approach #1:**

One way is to create an Aspect, with a point-cut expression that matches any method having this annotation.

Your aspect will then:

- Read the property value in the annotation
- Look up the required value an inject it into the class.

***AOP Kickstart***

Here's a guide to getting started with AOP in Spring

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aop_with_spring.htm

***Joinpoint matching***

Here's a reference that describes how to create a join-point that matches on annotations: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html

**Approach #2:**

Another way is to use a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.2/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) - this is essentially how a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer works.

- It will look at your bean definitions, and fetch the underlying class.
- It will then check for the annotation in the class, using reflection.
- It will update the bean definition to include injecting the property as per the value in the annotation.

. . actually I think approach #2 sounds more like what you want - all of the processing happens on "start-up". . . (In actual fact your modifying the bean recipes even before startup). . whereas if you used AOP, you'd be intercepting method invocations, which might be too late for you?

**Namespace Handler**

If you wanted you could even create your own Spring ***namespace handler*** to turn on your post processor in a terse way. Eg:

```
<myApp:injectFromDb />
```

as an alternative to:

```
<bean class="MyDatabaseLookupProcessorImpl etc, etc. />
```

**Update: Approach #3**

As of Spring 3.1 there's also the [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html), that will provide most of the plumbing for you, so you can achieve this with less code.

Comment: I guess this is another option: Use Spring 3.1 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and add a new PropertySource for my database properties: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you should be able to configure kind of properties repository bean and then use it in SpEL directly in @Value annotation.

Let's say you'd have bean called `propertiesRepository` in your context that implements following interface:

```
interface PropertiesRepository {
    String getProperty(String propertyName);
}
```

then on bean where you want to inject values you can use following expression

```
@Value("#{propertiesRepository.getProperty('my.property')}")
String myProperty;
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use @Value annotation by injecting database configuration in application environment itself.

I know this is an old question but I didn't find an exact solution. So documenting it here.

I have already answered the same on different [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465360/spring-boot-use-database-and-application-properties-for-configuration/).

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465360/spring-boot-use-database-and-application-properties-for-configuration/61793301#61793301) for exact solution to your problem.