# Custom annotation for @Value in Spring to update value during run time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am planning to write a custom annotation for my application, the objective of this annotation is used to read value from db and set it to variable during run time.

@myapplevalue("testing");

The bean is in singleton scope, so this annotation should behave like a getter method and get the value from db during runtime not during container start up.

I  have configured it to take during the container start up from db, but confused on how to get it dynamically, the motive to get new value without container restart.

I read the [Custom annotation like @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316575/custom-annotation-like-value) but look it is talking about setting value during start up, which I have already done.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? What if this value changes while a method of your bean is running? Is it supposed to be swapped out hot? Or do you want to check for a new value with every new session?

Comment: It should be hot swap.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do something like this - what you're trying to do is invoking a method when reading a variable. That kinda goes against a lot of Java principles. What you *could* do is make a centralized checker that updates the values. I.e. Spring would maintain a map of `value -> Collection of fields`, and whenever value is updated, the fields get reset as well.

Comment: Does I have to re-load the context for same?so all spring bean will be initialized again?